# submit a rails remote form with javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

In my rails app I have a remote form that looks something like this for example:

```
<%= form_tag some_path, :method => :get, :id => 'my-form', :remote => true do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search-field' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
<% end %>
```

Now i would like to submit this form via javascript and trigger all rails remote form callbacks. So far i have tried a few things but nothing seems to be working.

Things i have tried:

```
$('#my-form').trigger('onsubmit')

$.rails.callFormSubmitBindings( $('#search-form') )
```

but no luck so far. Any ideas?

Comment: What about `$("#my-form").submit()`? Does it fire the necessary callbacks? I know I've used similar in [my own code](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/BG-Tracker/blob/01a958924fc8cc67c0effa340e72ede43298b8fd/app/assets/javascripts/battlegroups.js.coffee#L5).

Answer (score -9, accepted):

You can just use .submit();

```
$("#my-form").submit();
```

Comment: Just want to add that it must be called on a jQuery object. For example if you do something like `$('.a').change(function { this.submit() })` it wont work. You must wrapp `this` in a jQuery object like `$(this)`. Then you can call the sumbit on that.

Comment: Warning : The form will NOT be submitted remotly (by ajax). Instead a full refresh will occur

Comment: Can you please update or remove this misleading answer? Submitting a remote form in a non-remote way makes no sense. Gopal's answer is the correct.

Answer (score 94):

In Rails 5.1+, which replaces the old `jquery-ujs` with a non-jquery `rails-ujs`, the above answers no longer work, always submitting the form via an HTML HTTP request.  This is how you trigger the new rails submit event handler:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('myform') // or $('#myform')[0] with jQuery
Rails.fire(elem, 'submit');
```

(Can't tell you how long it took me to figure that one out...) For some reason, the regular events don't bubble up properly to the delegated event handler [attached by rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/start.coffee#L55) using rails' new [delegate function](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.1.4/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/event.coffee#L34), when they are triggered by jQuery.

Comment: I'm getting this error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Rails`

Comment: This answer is old but this is new info for me. Thanks bro.

Comment: To solve the error `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Rails`, make sure you provide Rails as a plugin in `environment.js`: `environment.plugins.prepend('Provide',                        
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({                                                                        
    Rails: ['@rails/ujs']                                     
  })                                                                                         
) `

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! @acrogenesis I'm experiencing the same issue. I found out that you can use `jQuery.rails.fire` (or `$.rails.fire`) in Rails 5.1+ and 5.2+. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/start.coffee#L15) for the code on backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 81):

This is simply in Rails way :

```
 $("#myform").trigger('submit.rails');
```

Comment: This is the real answer. It preserve the ajax submitting behavior of a remote form. Thanks !

Comment: Mind the Comment of Ismael: You have to wrap your form in a jQuery object for remote submitting behaviour.
So not `myForm.submit()`, but `$(myForm).submit()`. I didn't spot the issue for quite some time either...

Comment: This should be marked the correct answer in modern versions of Rails

Answer (score 16):

How about using `rails_ujs` and simply do the following:

```
Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
```

(where `form` is a DOM Element)

This feels like a proper Rails way to do it.

You can check out the source here – https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/app/assets/javascripts/rails-ujs/utils/event.coffee#L34

Answer (score 8):

If you don't have access to `Rails` from your javascript, and you don't want to try to get it set up, there is an easier solution!

You can use `requestSubmit` on the html element, instead of submit, and it will work the way you'd expect it to, since `requestSubmit` raises a `submit` even, and `submit` does not.

See the difference between submit and requestSubmit here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit

In the case above, you could use:

```
$('#my-form')[0].requestSubmit()
```

Comment: This is a beauty. Wasn't even aware that `requestSubmit` was a thing and could be used to remotely submit the form. Thanks!

Comment: Caveat to this that burned us: This isn't supported on Internet Explorer or Safari, at all. https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlformelement_requestsubmit

Answer (score 4):

How about passing json from controller and capturing it by your js.

Now, controller's action as

```
respond_to do |format|
      if some condition
        format.json { render :json => {:success => true} }
        format.html{ redirect_to some_path, :notice => "successfully created" }
      else
        ...
      end
end
```

And capturing the json in js as

```
$('#my-form').bind 'ajax:success', (event,data) ->
  if(data.success == true)
    ...
```

Not exactly what you are looking for but hope this turns out to be of any help.

Comment: I believe he is simply asking how to submit the form itself.

Comment: wont the form be submitted remotely by itself to 'some_path' as stated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm updatting the answer to rails 6.

If you are having this issue in rails 6, it is likelly that you forgot to add the parameter "format: :js" to the form builder.

```
<%= form_tag some_path, :method => :get, :id => 'my-form', :remote => true,
         :format => :js do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], :id => 'search-field' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
<% end %>
```

You will also need to include a format.js in your controller.

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @model.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @model, notice: 'Model was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @model }
        format.js {
          logger.debug "this will run in the update was ok."
        }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js {
          logger.debug "this will run in the update was not ok."
        }
      end
    end
  end
```

Now, from the JavaScript, you can just call the submit to this form regularly.

```
this.form.submit()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old topic but I have been struggling with this now for some time and finally found a solution.

I had a form with `remote: true` that included a `file_field` and I wanted the form to submit automatically as soon as the user added the file. I tried `onchange: form.submit();` but that way the form was submitted as HTML.

My solution: clicking the (hidden) form submit button with JS:

```
onchange: $("#submit-button").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

@mltsy answer works perfect for me. However, wanted to reiterate that this requires the use of rails-ujs. If you've upgraded from an older version like me, you might still be using the jquery dependent jquery_ujs. If you're getting `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Rails` in your console, check your application.js and make sure you have rails-ujs or @mltsy's great answer won't work. I wanted to leave a comment instead of an answer, but Stack won't let me.