# Rails remote form submit through javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a very small simple form that edits a single checkbox, and submits automatically with AJAX when the checkbox is modified.  Here's the code, which [other SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570824/submit-a-rails-remote-form-with-javascript) imply should work:

```
    <%= form_for(workitem, :remote => true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.check_box :is_complete, :onchange => 'this.form.submit()' %>
    <% end %>
```

The problem is that this results in a full page HTML submit, rather than an AJAX submit.  How do I trigger an AJAX submit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$(this.form).submit();
```

Good 'ol jquery to the rescue.

Comment: Be warned this will only work if you only have one form element on your page

Answer (score 1):

This is simply in Rails way :

```
 $("#myform").trigger('submit.rails');
```

find it here : [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570824/submit-a-rails-remote-form-with-javascript/)