# Chrome scrolling to the top of the page after a remote form request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-chrome

Rails version: 5.2.2

Chrome version: 78.0.3904.87

While testing my website on Chrome today, I noticed that it scrolls to the top of the page whenever I submit an AJAX request. This behavior is undesirable and does not happen on other browsers, such as Firefox. I've tried debugging the issue but couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Here's what my form looks like:

```
<div id="container">
  <%= form_for(obj, method: :post, url: url, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <button id="obj-<%= obj.id %>-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary obj-btn" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left">
      Add
    </button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here's my JavaScript for submitting the form:

```
$("#container").on("click", "form > .obj-btn", function(e)
{
  $(this).tooltip('hide');

  var form = $(this).parent();

  form.submit();
});
```

After the request is sent to the server, the controller runs JavaScript in a `create.js.erb` file.

I looked at other threads that suggested adding `e.preventDefault()` or `return false;` in the submit handler, but none of them worked for me.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm wondering why you are trying to submit the form with javascript. When you use `:remote => true`, rails does that for you automatically.

Comment: @sureshprasanna70 It's because I have some extra logic (as you can see in the example) that I'd like to perform before submitting the form. Sometimes I have information stored on the DOM that is not available immediately after rendering the page, so I also use JavaScript to retrieve it and populate the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After puzzling over this problem for a long time, I found out the issue is with the [`font_awesome5_rails`](https://github.com/tomkra/font_awesome5_rails) gem that I'm using. This issue kept occurring even when I used AJAX to perform the request.

I've installed Font Awesome as an SVG using JavaScript, and whenever I take out the icons, Chrome no longer jumps to the top. I'm going to submit an issue and also look into the problem.

Answer (score 5):

**You should be listening for and catching the submit event on your form, not the button click event.** If you use `e.preventDefault()` in that case, you should be able to preclude the default submission behavior causing your page to refresh. So your approach would resemble something to this effect, roughly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // ***** Listen to submit event on the form itself ***** //
  $('#form').submit(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    // Capture data from form 
    // and manually submit by AJAX here

  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer and for your patience! I'm still experiencing the issue even when listening for and catching the `submit` event.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not manually submitting by AJAX when catching the `submit` event; I'm calling `return true` since all of the data is already on my form. It seems Rails has [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570824/submit-a-rails-remote-form-with-javascript/46573492#46573492) with remote forms and using JavaScript to submit them.

Comment: @Alexander - No problem and thanks for the info. To clarify and as flagged in a comment above, I don't think you should be handling your submission with both inline logic (i.e. 'method: post`) AND the listener callback (currently listening for just click). Because you have "extra logic" to perform before submission and because you want to prevent page refresh, I recommened using the on submit listener callback above to handle submission in this case: prevent default, fetch form values from DOM, perform any extra logic/validation, and then submit via ajax.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `e.preventDefault()`, the page wouldn't refresh at all after the AJAX request is successful. So you need to refresh the page in the javascript with `window.location.reload()`

Comment: I would not like the page to be refreshed or scrolled when the user submits a form.

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form is not an ajax request, thus the browser (typically) goes to the top of the page. It is the same (more or less) as navigating to another page.

You have two options (as some other answers suggest):

1. Make a real ajax request (such as $.ajax, some native method or the methods that your client side framework gives you).
2. Embed javascript on the page to automatically scroll you to the page section you want to be.

I think the first option is what you are looking for as the second one may cause bouncing the page up and down.

Answer (score 0):

By default when a button inside a form is clicked, it will submit the form causing it to reload the page.

Another solution that i can think of is to change the button to an `<a>` tag.  This will prevent the form from posting, however you need to handle the form submission manually. hope this helps.